# All Google sites unreachable

Tags: 14.04, networking, google

I cannot reach Google sites by browser on Ubuntu 14.04.
It is not due to Chrome, as Firefox gives the same problem. It happens also in incognito mode.
It is not due to the network, as all other devices connected to the same WiFi are working.
All other sites work, except Twitter. Some sites lag, and on AskUbuntu I get a message saying:

"Ask Ubuntu requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load"

How did I block Google, and how do I un-block it?

**EDIT**

Output of ping (I interrupted it after some seconds as it just hangs)

```
$ ping google.com
PING google.com (216.58.200.192) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
13 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 12096ms
```

Output of traceroute

```
$ traceroute6 google.com
connect: Network is unreachable
```

**EDIT - SOLUTION**

As suggesed by Georgi, I renamed the /etc/hosts file, effectively removing it, and solved the problem. Chances are, I had accidentally changed it.

Comment: Have you ping any site like say google.com to see if your network is working properly?

Comment: If I ping google.com I have a 100% packet loss. I can ping 8.8.8.8 with no problems. I also tried to ping www.askubuntu.com and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be DNS related issue but some of the sites are working so there are less chances of this.

There can be several different reasons of this.

First let's confirm if it is a browser specific problem or not.

Open terminal

```
ping google.com
```

If it is pinging then it is browsers issue or issue with port80  or port 443

If not pinging

FIREWALL
Check whether your firewall is running or not

```
sudo systemctl status firewalld
```

If running turn off firewall

```
sudo systemctl stop firewalld
```

To turnoff permanently

```
sudo systemctl disable firewalld
```

Try pinging again if not pinging try checking IPTABLE rules

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As per edit, I can ping some sites (like askubuntu, of facebook, for instance) but not google.com. I don't have systemctl but I checked the firewall status with ufw status and it is not active. How should I proceed to check iptable rules?

Answer (score 1):

Can you update the case with the output from the following commands:

```
ping google.com
traceroute google.com
cat /etc/hosts
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited the question. The output from the last command is >5000 lines, not sure how to post it correctly here, sorry...

Comment: This is quite big hosts file, which is quite strange.
Can you try to temporary disable the hosts file (mv /etc/hosts /etc/hosts.bak) and try the ping and traceroute (not traceroute6) commands again?

Comment: IT WORKED! I can ping google.com and access google from browser! Thank you very much! DO you have any idea on what could have happened and why?

Comment: I suspect that you (or a program you installed) altered your /etc/hosts file:
[link]http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/hosts.5.html
You can create new /etc/hosts file - just make sure to include the **127.0.0.1 localhost** line in it so your programs can resolve the localhost hostname.

Comment: I see. It makes sense, although I cannot think exactly of what could have done it. Thanks again.

Comment: Honestly, I'd get **really** suspicious if my `/etc/hosts` file had entries I didn't put there, especially if it has more than 5,000 lines.

Comment: Seems that you marked Mangesh Divate's reply as Answer to your question, while it was not. This can mislead other users, experiencing the same issue.